# Porting AS3 to iPhone App

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3

Anybody know any good tut's for iPhone development? I have written a game in AS3 and have excellent knowledge of PHP/OOP etc but I cannot get my head around the iPhone SDK or the objective C syntax and structure.

Answer (score 1):

A great start is the stanford course (CS193P) which is available for download from iTunes University.  That will get you general iOS programming knowledge.

After that, depending on the style of your game, it's worth looking at Cocos2d (an open-source 2D graphics library).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tut for the Obj-C basics: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 1):

I'm in similar situation and these are the steps I'm following and the books I bought:

1. Learn Objective C: "[Programming in Objective C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325861)" by Stephen Kochan
2. Learn Cocoa & AppKit: "[Cocoa Programming for MacOS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)"
3. Learn Cocoa Touch (specific framework for iPHone): "[iPhone for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013705842X)"

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. Having just learnt AS3 I'm feeling more confident stepping back into the iPhone because I believe AS3 feels more like C and may help the transition.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend *Beginning iPhone 4 Development* by Mark LaMarche. There's also a "sequel" to this book. The Apple doc on Objective-C is also pretty good when it comes to understanding just the Objective-C language:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2

Answer (score 1):

A popular resource is Standford University's lectuture slides for the iPhone Application Development unit available in pdf @ http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/